# Uncaught PDOException problem with SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with my SQL code, when i try do this code below i get error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`gameforest`.`game`, CONSTRAINT `game_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`platform_id`) REFERENCES `platform` (`id`)) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameForest\classes\admin.class.php:120 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameForest\classes\admin.class.php(120):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameForest\admin\gameAction.php(25): Admin->addGame()
>
> 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\GameForest\admin\gameAction.php(43): GameAction->__construct() #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameForest\classes\admin.class.php on line 120

I try this sql query:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO game (game_id, game_name, image_src, genre_id, developer_id, release_date, platform_id, game_price, game_description, processor, graphic, ram) VALUES (null, :gameName, :gameImg, :gameGenre, :gameDev, :gameDate, :gamePlatform, :gamePrice, :gameDesc, :gameProc, :gameGraph, :gameRam)";
$stmt = $this->dbcon->prepare($sql);
```

// Insert method

```php
public function addGame() {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO game (game_id, game_name, image_src, genre_id, developer_id, release_date, platform_id, game_price, game_description, processor, graphic, ram) VALUES (null, :gameName, :gameImg, :gameGenre, :gameDev, :gameDate, :gamePlatform, :gamePrice, :gameDesc, :gameProc, :gameGraph, :gameRam)";
    $stmt = $this->dbcon->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':gameName', $this->gameName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameImg', $this->imageSrc);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameGenre', $this->genreId);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameDev', $this->developerId);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameDate', $this->releaseDate);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gamePlatform', $this->platformId);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gamePrice', $this->gamePrice);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameDesc', $this->gameDescription);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameProc', $this->processor);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameGraph', $this->graphic);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gameRam', $this->ram);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I expecting to insert that datas in database.

Comment: Can you add your database table structure to the post please?

Comment: As the error message says, **it can not write a child row**. You are using constraints who do not allow to insert that data.

Comment: In short: You've explicitly created `game_ibfk_1` to prevent something. Now you're trying to do that something.